# Choosing SDK colors ios - code

Tags: objective-c, colors

I know how to set colors in objective-C like this `[UIColor lightGray]`. Im wondering how to you code colors that are part of xcode such as silver, ocean, aqua etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways I know of to create more custom colors.

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(220/255.0) green:(210/255.0) blue(130/255.0) alpha(1)];
```

This is one example of how to create many custom colors using green red and blue.

Comment: Thanks Im also aware of this way, but its the system/crayon colors i am looking for

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to have such specific colors like that without creating them custom. But I could be wrong.